# How do I modify selected items in asp:listbox for use in a proper string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets say I wanted to create an application for a user to select trouble departments for reporting purposes. The user would go in and select multiple trouble departments from a `asp:ListBox` and when the user hits send the email would read,

***`We are having trouble in the following departments: DepartmentA, DepartmentB.`***

What I have been able to is figure out how to properly loop the items out from the loop, however the last item has a ***`,`*** at the end of the last item. For example instead of reading the proper way as noted above it looks like this:

***`We are having trouble in the following departments: DepartmentA, DepartmentB,.`***

Here is my code:

```
string DeptID = string.Empty;
foreach (ListItem li in lstDSXDepartment.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected == true)
    {
        DeptID += li.Value + ",";
    }
}

Response.Write("We are having trouble with the following Departments: " + DeptID + ".");
```

How do I fix the string so that the comma does not show at the end of list of selections?

Comment: You could trim the last character out of the string after the loop finishes.

Comment: Alas, Trim() fixes another simple issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a trim function to remove the unwanted comma.

```
DeptID = DeptID.TrimEnd(',');
```

Use after the loop, before writing.

*Note*: The `TrimEnd` function returns a new copy that is modified of the original string so you have to store it back into your original variable.  This is because strings are **immutable** in `C#`.

Comment: Why did I not think of that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [string.join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is much easier.

```
var ids = lstDSXDepartment.Items
    .Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(x=> x.Selected)
    .Select(x=> x.Value);
string text = string.Join(",", ids);
```

### Other thought:

If you want to use your original method, you should consider using [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instead of String because **String is immutable**.

StringBuilder will significantly improve the performance depending on the number of Items.